# Busbar with 6 mains needs to be replaced with one 150 amp single main

Tags: electrical-panel

In order to install a generator lockout, I would need to have a service panel with a single Main breaker, mine has six mains. I have another panel but it’s to tall and would reconfigure everything and not up to it. What’s the the possibility that I could a replacement busbar with a single main 150 amp main breaker?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of your panel as well as the labeling on the inside of the panel's door?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, I have been seeing a lot of panels like that lately, and it is simply impossible.  **The bus bars in this type of panel are permanently attached to utility** and cannot be moved/removed.

Somewhere you must have a subpanel that powers most of your household loads.  Your best bet is to retrofit a sliding-plate generator interlock accessory into that subpanel, so the loads in there can be thrown to utility or generator.

If you want to power loads inside the Rule of Six main panel, then your best bet is to install a new subpanel right next to it, and install a generator interlock between its main breaker and the backfeed breaker for the generator.  Then, move any breakers you please from the Rule of Six panel to the new subpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Not much chance. Sorry. What you have is a commonly referred to as "split bus panel". If you could source the needed components (not likely), it would still involve gutting most of the panel and a lot of re-wiring.

Have you thought of a sub-panel with a MTS (Manual Transfer Switch) and moving important circuits to the new sub-panel with the generator interlock (MTS)? I did that at a previous home and it worked out pretty well.

Comment: Maybe I should consider that seriously.